# Front end inline editing?

Tags: plugins, front-end, content, wysiwyg

I was wondering if it is possible to allow my users to create posts from the front end in an inline editor, similar to content creation on Medium.com? I know there are many options out there for inline editing, but not any for end users to post from the front-end that I'm aware of.

Currently I am using Gravity Forms which allows my users to create posts from the front-end, but it is through a form and not inline. Is there a way to do this so that a post is created after submitting some sort of inline form? Any assistance with this would be really appreciated since I am kind of lost.

Comment: Whats ur exact question? do u want to someone code it for u?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WP JSON REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org) in conjunction with [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). It works pretty well with [custom endpoints](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/). Just be sure to use [nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```